# for_each for resource vs dynamic

Tags: dynamic, foreach, terraform

In short, I have a resource and a dynamic block both use for_each for a string value which is nullable by default. In a dynamic block, the handling is different from the resources. Can someone explain why and what's behind it?

---

Now the long details:

That's the input

```
variable "kms_arn" {
  description = "ARN of KMS fetched"
  type        = string
  nullable    = true
  default     = null
}
variable "policy" {
  description = "Bucket policy which is assigned to bucket and allows access to it"
  type        = string
  nullable    = true
  default     = null
}
```

This is the dynamic block which uses `!= null ? [0] : []`

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "enc" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id

  rule {

    dynamic "apply_server_side_encryption_by_default" {
      for_each = var.kms_arn != null ? [0] : []

      content {
        kms_master_key_id = var.kms_arn
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }

    dynamic "apply_server_side_encryption_by_default" {
      for_each = var.kms_arn == null ? [0] : []

      content {
        sse_algorithm     = "AES256"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

This is the resources block and here I have to use `!= null ? toset(["1"]) : []` as without `toset` and a string, it is not working and complains.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy" {
  for_each = var.policy != null ? toset(["1"]) : []

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  policy = var.policy
}
```

If I use the same way I use for dynamic blocks for the resource as well, I get the following error.

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on modules/ressources/s3/main.tf line 64, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy":
│   64:   for_each = var.policy != null ? [0] : []
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.policy is null
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type
│ list of number.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question essentially is asking "why is a `list` type allowed as a value for the meta-parameter argument `for_each` within a `dynamic` block, but not within a `resource` block?" If we check the [Terraform DSL collection type documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#collection-types):

> list(...): a sequence of values identified by consecutive whole numbers starting with zero.
> set(...): a collection of unique values that do not have any secondary identifiers or ordering.

The important differentiation here is that a `set` type is unordered whereas a `list` type is ordered. Therefore the question can rephrased as "why must the value be unordered within a `resource` block and not within a `dynamic` block?"

This is basically for two reasons:

1. The `dynamic` block is within the attribute schema of a resource, and plan differentiation, and state setting and getting, for attributes does not need to be unordered.
2. The resource block is within the top level namespace of the state, and the resource data model is set and assigned as a `struct` that is not cognizant of ordering. Accurate Terraform state setting and getting requires unordered resources.

Therefore the `list` is allowed for the dynamic block `for_each` metaparameter, but not within the `resource`.

There is also a side question of simplifying the values. This can be accomplished most easily be modifying the variable declarations as such:

```
variable "kms_arn" {
  description = "ARN of KMS fetched"
  type        = set(string)
  default     = []
}
variable "policy" {
  description = "Bucket policy which is assigned to bucket and allows access to it"
  type        = set(string)
  default     = []
}
```

and the config:

```
dynamic "apply_server_side_encryption_by_default" {
  for_each = var.kms_arn

  content {
    kms_master_key_id = each.value
    sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy" {
  for_each = var.policy

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  policy = each.value
}
```

where the standard lazily evaluated collection will short-circuit when the value is empty i.e. constructor with no values: `[]`.

Comment: Amazing!! To the point, thank you.