# Terraform optional resource based on variable and cannot be determined problem

Tags: foreach, count, terraform

I'm on terraform version 1.5.7. I want to build a module where I can add a bucket policy as a variable, and **only if there is a policy provided the aws_s3_bucket_policy resource should be created**.

Furthermore, I assumed I need to use either count or for_each and a variable with a different default value, so I can determine this is something NULLABLE.

Sadly, this does not seem to work as the "attributes [.] cannot be determined" by terraform and I would need to use target, even though the policy is a plain text and written inside the code.

Any help would be appreciated!

### count

**module - variables**

```
variable "name" {
  description = "Name of S3 bucket"
  type        = string
}
variable "policy" {
  description = "Bucket policy, which is assigned to a bucket and allows access to it. Defaults to null"
  type        = string
  nullable    = true
  default     = null
}
```

**module - main**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket        = var.name
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy" {
  count      = var.policy != null ? 1 : 0
  bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  policy     = var.policy
}
```

**usage**

```
locals {
  name = "testOptionalPolicy"
}

module "s3" {
  source                = "../../modules/s3"
  name                  = local.name
  policy                = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${local.name}/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

**Error receiving**

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on ../../modules/s3/main.tf line 72, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy":
│   72:   count      = var.policy != null ? 1 : 0
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be
│ created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
╵
```

### for_each

If I replace the count with `for_each = var.policy != null ? [1] : []` the error changes, but the problem stays the same.

**Error receiving**

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on ../../modules/s3/main.tf line 72, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "policy":
│   72:   for_each   = var.policy != null ? [1] : []
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.policy is a string, known only after apply
│
│ The "for_each" map includes keys derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full
│ set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.
│
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map keys statically in your configuration and place apply-time results only
│ in the map values.
│
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a
│ second time to fully converge.
╵
```

P.S.: This seems related to my last question, even it's somehow different. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77186992/for-each-for-resource-vs-dynamic) reference will help someone.

Comment: That `count` and the `for_each` should work, what version of terraform do you have?  ... I did notice a small typo in your code `= = <<EOF`

Comment: I run on 1.5.7 and corrected the typo

Comment: could you add more details about how you implement and use the terraform module and what are you trying to plan/apply ?

Comment: Do you mean, what's the aim? I want to have a S3 module which allows adding policies or not but want to avoid using `-target`.

Comment: FWIW, I would not expect this problem to occur on Terraform v1.7 (the current latest minor release) because Terraform is now able to internally track whether an unknown value could possibly be null, and it knows that a multi-line template expression (like you have here) can never produce `null` as a result, even if Terraform doesn't know exactly what characters will be in the string yet.

Comment: The problem occurs on v1.5 (and earlier) because Terraform only knows that `var.policy` is unknown, and therefore it cannot decide whether `var.policy != null`.

Comment: I tried 1.6 and both for_each and count work now. Thanks @MartinAtkins

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood the problem, which is the same I have faced many times. I almost always tend to avoid the `count` as much as possible and prefer `for_each`.

First I declare a static set.

```
locals {
  s3_key = toset(<if criteria are satisfied>?["my_key"]:[])
}
```

Then in any resource that has to be conditionally created I refer to the key.

```
module "s3" {
  for_each = local.s3_key
  source                = "../../modules/s3"
  name                  = local.name
  policy                = <<EOF
  ...
}
```

However, remember that with this approach any resource that needs to access some output variable has to be *for_eached* as well with such key.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_role" {
  for_each = local.s3_key
  name = module.s3[each.value].any_output_variable
  .....
}
```

In this way you can build entire chains of depending resources.

Comment: Did you test this with a newer version? I receive the same error using `for_each   = toset(var.policy != null ? ["policy"] : [])`